# Getting error like "Type qualifier 'std' must be a struct or class name in C++

Tags: c++

When i compile the code below, i got the error like Type qualifier 'std' must be a struct or class name. Kindly find the code below-

```
#include <iostream>

int foo(int i)
{
  return 2;
}

double foo(double d)
{
  return 4.0;
}

struct Computer
{
  int foo(int i)
  {
    return 8; 
  }
};

struct Gateway : public Computer
{
  double foo(double d)
  {
    return 16.0; 
  }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  Gateway g;

  std::cout << foo(1) + foo(1.0) + g.foo(1) + g.foo(1.0) << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Kindly check it and suggest how to resolve it.

Comment: It compiles fine for me...

Comment: How are you compiling this? It looks OK.

Comment: What compiler do you use to compile that, gcc? Did you try g++?

Comment: Can you please post the complete error log? And also point out where in the provided source the error is?

Comment: It compiles file and prints the value 38. compile using g++ <your_program> and tell us what happens. Otherwise please share the exact error message. Even snapshot would be helpful

Comment: @Joachim:It shows error in line 33 like type qualifier 'std' must be struct or class name and statement missing (;). I am using turbo C++.

Comment: Sounds like you need a newer, standards compliant compiler.

Comment: Ok it works fine with gcc but i confused for the answer as 38. Kindly explain it in short how it comes 38?

Comment: @user3090837: If you have a new question, then you should ask a new question. In short: because both calls to `g.foo` call `Gateway::foo(double)`, so the total is `2+4+16+16=38`. One might expect the first `g.foo` to call `Computer::foo(int)`, but it doesn't since the declaration of `Gateway::foo` hides any base-class functions with the same name.

Answer (score 2):

[Your code compiles and runs fine.](http://ideone.com/uaTU3t)

You are getting this error because your compiler is not compliant with [the C++ standard](http://isocpp.org/std/the-standard).

[Turbo C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbo_C++) is horrendously outdated.

It is time to get a new, free, standard compliant compiler. [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) for example.

---

In answer to your second question, in the comments, `Gateway::foo` *hides* `Computer::foo`, which is why `Gateway::foo` is invoked for both `int` and `double` arguments. If this is not what you intended, you could alter your `struct` like so:

```
struct Gateway : public Computer
{
    using Computer::foo;

    double foo(double d)
    {
        return 16.0;
    }
};
```

[See it run!](http://ideone.com/qVlIAq)